# Android studio 3 issue when trying "hello world"

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm new to android development. Hope someone could help me out..

I'm trying Android Studio 3.0.1, and try to create a project as "Hello world". All steps are just follow the default setting.

But it failed when building the project. The error message says:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Required by:
>       project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/127.0.1.4] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Connection refused: connect

I searched around in google and stackoverflow. There's some hint saying that in Android Studio 3.0+ I should modify build.gradle file with the repositories section and the dependencies  section: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And I did that.

Here's my top level build.gradle file:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's my app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.happybirthday"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

then I got the error message:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Required by:
>       project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Connection refused: connect

I'm using proxy connection but the network should be ok.

I do appreciate if anyone could give me some guide. Thanks.

Zong

Comment: update SDK tools

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Tools--->android--->sdk Manager

Comment: checked there, I have 26/27 installed already

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

these line from your app/build.gradle file and then clean project -> rebuild 
this may help

Comment: thanks @Omi. I commented these 3 lines, but still the same error message.